# How to exclude dependencies of other subproject in Gradle build?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I am developing a sub-project that is a part of the huge multi-project Gradle build. I need some Java classes from these other sub-projects, but I do not need any dependencies they drag in because some libraries I use require different versions of these.

I initially configured the needed subprojects as

```
compile project(':other_needed_sub_project')
```

however in this case `gradle eclipse` task adds projects to the project tree. They dependencies appear on the class path, causing my application to pick the wrong versions. In Eclipse, included projects seem having priority over specified libraries.

As a working solution, I currently build jars of the required sub-projects with existing Maven build and then use

```
compile files('../other_needed_sub_project/target/dist/other_needed_sub_project.jar')
```

that is exactly that I need - no libs attached. However this means that I must run a different build before building my subproject with Gradle.

Could Gradle build the needed sub-projects and then only add references to they final jars in my Eclipse configuration?

Comment: This is considered to be a faulty behaviour of the gradle eclipse task. The behaviour has been fixed in the upcoming 2.5 gradle release. You might want to give a latest gradle nightly build a try. Also, you'll find a full description of the changes here: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/2f55576ebdb85e3d9122943e09ac7a5e939445f3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could exclude all transitive dependencies of a dependency:

```
compile('groupId:artifactId:version') {
    transitive = false
}
```

Or you could, but I do certainly not recommend this exclude every dependency by hand like this:

```
compile('groupId:artifactId:version') {
    exclude module: 'groupId:artifactId:version'
    ...
}
```

Comment: but this does not work with compile project(..) how is this an answer?

Comment: @vach You need an extra set of parenthesis for:

`compile (project (':other_needed_subproject')) { transitive = false }`

Answer (score 6):

You can exclude a module from dependency

```
dependencies { 
    implementation (project(":sub_project")) {
        exclude group: 'grp1', module: 'mdl1'
        exclude group: 'grp2'
        exclude module: 'mdl2'
    }
}
```